# I got message this message in rails "The dependency tzinfo-data"

Tags: ruby, elementary, ruby-on-rails

I just install ruby on rails couple days ago and every time a create a new project in the console I got this message:

```
The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby`.
```

but when I try to install like:

```
bundle lock --add-platform mingw
```

I got this message:

```
Could not locate Gemfile
```

Do you guys have some idea what I do bout this message???

Comment: I don't know for sure but please try to do what the message is asking you to do. Try to run `bundle lock --add-platform mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby` and not just `bundle lock --add-platform mingw`.

Comment: It doesn't work It send me the same message: Could not locate Gemfile

Comment: There is a comprehensive guide for installing `ruby on rails`: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem on mac osx El capitan and this is how i solved it.
FIRST this is the error message i got after running this command

$ rails new my-app -d mysql

The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for ruby but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby`.
-Note: I tried running the command while am in the application folder where i install my apps till i had to cd my-app directory(root of my app)
- Fist you cd into the root directory of the app you are creating
- bundle lock --add-platform mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby
-To install the missing dependecies.
-For my case i only did this bundle lock --add-platform  jruby
-And it worked like a charm try that should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

This gem is **unnecessary** for apps that will be running on Ubuntu (or any Unix-based system) and can be safely removed from the gemfile unless your rails app is running on a Windows machine.

Per the [gem's author](https://github.com/tzinfo/tzinfo-data/issues/12#issuecomment-279554001):

> If you want to get rid of the message you can do one of the following:
>
> 1. Remove the platforms option from the gem 'tzinfo-data' line in the Gemfile (and run bundle update). This will cause tzinfo to use tzinfo-data as its data source on all platforms instead of using the system time zone data.
> 2. Remove the gem 'tzinfo-data' line from the Gemfile. This will cause tzinfo to always try and use the system time zone data. A TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound exception will be raised if you try and run your app on Windows.
> 3. Run bundle lock --add-platform mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, jruby to add mingw, mswin, x64_mingw, and jruby to the list of platforms Bundler will include in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

The `Could not locate Gemfile` message is coming up because you're not in the project directory. `cd` into the project directory before running any `bundle` command.

- `cd [path/to/your/rails/project]`
- `bundle lock --add-platform mingw`